# MySQL join, ORDER BY RAND() then sort ASC (preferably using Sequelize)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'd like some help with this MySQL query. Ideally, I'd generate it using the node.js Sequelize ORM.

The tables are:

```
Questions: id, question
Answers: id, question_id, answer
```

My Sequelize code is:

```
models.questions.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      $notIn: not_in
    }
  },
    order: [['id','ASC'], [models.answers, 'id', 'ASC']],
    attributes: ['id', 'question'],
    include: [{
        model: models.answers,
        attributes: ['id', 'question_id', 'answer'],
    }]
})
```

With `not_in` set to `-1`, Sequelize generates this query:

```
SELECT `questions`.`id`, 
       `questions`.`question`, 
       `answers`.`id`          AS `answers.id`, 
       `answers`.`question_id` AS `answers.question_id`, 
       `answers`.`answer`      AS `answers.answer` 
FROM   `questions` AS `questions` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `answers` AS `answers` 
                    ON `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id` 
WHERE  `questions`.`id` NOT IN ( -1 ) 
ORDER  BY `questions`.`id` ASC, 
          `answers`.`id` ASC
```

And results in:

```
id  |   question    |   answers.id  |   answers.question_id |   answers.answer
13  |   first question  |   17  |   13  |   1st answer
13  |   first question  |   23  |   13  |   2nd answer
13  |   first question  |   24  |   13  |   3rd answer
14  |   second question |   18  |   14  |   1st answer
14  |   second question |   21  |   14  |   2nd answer
14  |   second question |   22  |   14  |   3rd answer
15  |   third question  |   19  |   15  |   1st answer
15  |   third question  |   20  |   15  |   2nd answer
```

I would like this result, but with the question sorted randomly.

So instead of 13, 14 then 15, it could be 14, 15, 13, but with answers still aligned with their question and sorted by `answers.id`.

Would appreciate any pointers for the Sequelize code or MySQL query to get such a result. Thanks!

I've tried adding `ORDER BY RAND()` in various places but it ends up shuffling the answers as well.

P.S.
As an aside, earlier I needed this with just one question picked randomly, for which I used:

```
SELECT `questions`.`id`       AS `question_id`, 
       `questions`.`question` AS `question`, 
       `answers`.`id`         AS `answer_id`, 
       `answers`.`answer`     AS `answer` 
FROM   (SELECT `questions`.`id`, 
               `questions`.`question` 
        FROM   `questions` AS `questions` 
        WHERE  (SELECT `question_id` 
                FROM   `answers` AS `answers` 
                WHERE  `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id` 
                       AND questions.id NOT IN ( -1 ) 
                LIMIT  1) IS NOT NULL 
        ORDER  BY RAND() 
        LIMIT  1) AS `questions` 
       INNER JOIN `answers` AS `answers` 
               ON `questions`.`id` = `answers`.`question_id` 
ORDER  BY `answers`.`question_id`, 
          `answers`.`id`
```

Which would return, e.g.:

```
id  |   question    |   answers.id  |   answers.question_id |   answers.answer
14  |   second question |   18  |   14  |   1st answer
14  |   second question |   21  |   14  |   2nd answer
14  |   second question |   22  |   14  |   3rd answer
```

Comment: Not currently possible - you could use `include.separate` though, which will run two separate queries https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4875

Answer (score 1):

In plain MySQL:

```
SELECT  ...
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  RAND() AS rnd, id FROM questions ) AS r
    JOIN  questions AS q ON q.id = r.id
    JOIN  answers AS a   ON a.question_id = q.id
    ORDER BY  r.rnd, a.id
```